# is it right to start a sentence with the word "with"

Tags: british-english

To,

The Competent Authority,

Subject: Application for the Commercial Meter

with due veneration and most humbly it is requested to your kind-self that I the undersigned being a representative of the Company is hereby applied for the commercial electricity meter. it is further requested that kindly issue directions to the concerned quarter for the subject purpose. Your timely favourable action in this regard will be highly solicited.

HR/Admin Manager
Muhammad Saleem Bhatti
Al-Ghani Group of Companies

Comment: what are your doubts?

Comment: The sentence-initial "with" is about the least of your problems in that paragraph.

Comment: If your purpose is a Monty Pythonesque parody of sounding like addressing the King of England circa 1750 while merely writing a request to the power company to get an electricity meter, then I give you an A for your humor attempt.

Comment: This is not a proof-reading site.

Comment: @curious-proofreader Look at the OP's name. It could be a genuine attempt by an Indian or Pakistani person. They do employ much more formality and  obeisance to persons in authority than is the custom in western countries.

Comment: @curious-proofreader! yes you are absolutely right. I am Pakistani and I learned such formalities while working in the Government of the Punjab, Pakistan

Comment: infact I met a CEO regarding an interview and he start dialogues over this technique i.e. beginning of sentence with the clause / word "with"; whereas, I was trying to convenience him that it may but he was denying that there are grammar rules which deny

Comment: that's why just to clarify myself I joined this group

Answer (score 0):

With no choice but to answer the simplest way I say yes, you can start a sentence with, with.

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect, I think you got the answer.

Answer (score -1):

> With adequate money, life can be so much easier.

To answer your question, yes.

The least you could do is to capitalize the first letter of the first word of every sentence.